# find the $p(x) = 0.00125x^4+x-3, where x = 300?$

Tags: polynomials

Find the
$$P(x) = 0.00125x^4+x-3$$ where is $$x=300$$

How can i solve this equation

What formula i used to solve this?

Thanks for the solution

Comment: You can just substitute it.

Comment: I dont know about this

Comment: $P(x) = \frac{1}{800} x^4+x-3$

Comment: "I dont know about this"  You don't know that $P(300) = 0.00125*300^4 + 300 -3 $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(300) = 0.00125(300)^4+x-3 =125(10^{-5})(81)(10^8)+297=(125)(81)(1000)+297=(125)(80+1)(1000)+297=(10125)(1000)+297=10125297$$

Answer (score 1):

All they are asking is for you to just "plug it in".

$P(x) = P(x) = 0.00125x^4+x-3$ so if $x = 300$ then

$P(300) =  0.00125*(300)^4+(300)-3$ and all they are doing is asking you to figure what it is.

It may help to use power of $10$ exponents.  And to realize that $0.125 = \frac 18$

$0.00125*300^4 = (0.125 \times 10^{-2})*(3\times 10^2)^4=\frac 18\times 10^{-2}\times 3^4\times 10^8=$

$\frac {81}8 \times 10^6 = 10\frac 18 \times 10^6=$

$10.125 \times 10^6 = 10,125,000$

So $P(300)= 0.00125*(300)^4+(300)-3= 10,125,000 + 300 - 3 = 10,125,297$.

....

.... or there's always a calculator .....